# GCC Compilation yields error in VS Code external terminal, but the compilation works fine when opening terminal in another window

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, compiler-errors, gcc-warning

I am trying to compile .c file in VS Code terminals, but when executing

```
gcc test.c -o test.exe
```

the VS Code external terminal will yield this error:

```
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create C:\Users\
```

However, executing the above code in a normal terminal will work just fine.

I am using Windows 11 and the GCC is built using MSYS2. I want to emphasize that I am not using the integrated terminal, and integrated terminal yielded the same error.

So far I have tried

1. Using different shells. I have tried powershell, git bash, and cmd; all of them yield the same results.
2. give admin permission (and restarted) to vs code, but the same error persists.
3. checked the execution policy - it is always unrestricted

Answer (score 0):

**1. Check Default Shell:**
Verify that the default shell used by VS Code's integrated terminal is the same as the shell you're using in the separate terminal window. To check and change the default shell in VS Code:

Open the command palette (Ctrl + Shift + P).
Type "Select Default Shell" and choose the shell you want to use.
Restart VS Code and try compiling again.
**Check Terminal Profile:**
Ensure that the terminal profile you're using in VS Code's integrated terminal is configured correctly. Sometimes, different terminal profiles can have different configurations (like environment variables, paths, etc.).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541

Answer (score 0):

Electron can be a little finnicky sometimes so you can try killing all instances of vscode in task manager manually and then running as administrator again and if that doesn't work try `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in the terminal.

Comment: thank you for your response! I tried restarting my computer after granting admin privilege and that did not work. Also the execution policy is unrestricted all along,